# Spring MVC - Double Slash in RequestMapping causes bugs in CSS link

Tags: java, html, css, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller, and i put double slash on it.

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/vehicles/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addVehicle(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("vehicle", new Vehicle());
    return "newvehicle";
 }
```

And the CSS link:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
```

What happened is when I have double slash, the css link of the html was not working. So I tried to just use single slash

```
 RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and it worked. But I want to have a double slash. What do you think is the problem. I think the directory is not the problem because it worked with single slash.

Comment: It has nothing to do with double or single slashes. You shouldn't use relative links for your stylesheets use absolute links.

Comment: @M.Deinum how can I do that?

Comment: Use the URL tag for that, either the one from spring or from the JSTL library.

Comment: were you able to resolve this @Lester ?

Comment: @Sampada Not the way I want to. Maybe you have some suggestions?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @Sampada to get the CSS files from a bower_components folder.

Comment: @Lester, I am not familiar with bower. But i do know Restful services. If you wan to GET something, you write the GET API so that HTTP GET call on the url reaches there. What you do inside that method is up to you. That's java coding. You need to either update this post, or ask a new question altogether.

Comment: @Sampada thank you for the advice